# Spring-Kafka @KafkaHandlers not consuming respective java Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I know it has been asked multiple time, however, i cant find the solution yet. I am able to consume a specific Java Object by my @KafkaListener(On a class level) and works perfectly fine, however, When i try to consume multiple different JSON Objects from the same topic( I use @KafkaListener at class level and @KafkaHandler at the method level, each @KafkaHandler method expecting different Object), it always produces LinkedHashMap. I can parse this and get the data and do a factory pattern to generate different Instances based on a json field, however, i do not want to do that when Spring can auto detect a specific @KafkaHandler for routing the message. 
How do i consume different JSON object from a single topic with single @KafkaListener.

I am using below configs:

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> abcConsumerFactory() {       
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();       
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"group-1");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class );
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class, false)); 

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> abcListenerContainerFactory() {      
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(abcConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
    }
```

If i use the actual class(Foo or Bar) instead of Object in above configs it works fine for that particular objects, However, when i try to generalize, it does not go to the specific @KafkaHandler, and instead goes to a @KafkaHandler with Payload type LinkedHashMap(I was trying to check if it gets delivered to a @KafkaHandler)

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> abcListenerContainerFactory() {      
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(abcConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
    }

Class:  

    @KafkaListener(topics={"abc_gh"}, containerFactory = "abcListenerContainerFactory")
    @Service
    public class MyListener {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void consumeMessage(@Payload Foo f) {
        //only comes here when i use Foo in my configs instead of Object

    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void consumeMessage22(@Payload Bar b) {
        //only comes here when i use Bar in my configs instead of Object

    }   

    @KafkaHandler
    public void consumeMessage77(@Payload LinkedHashMap bc) {

        //comes here when i use Object in the configs, even if i expect a Foo or a Bar object

    }               
    }
```

One thing i want to share is the Producer is not using Spring-Kafka.

I dont know what i am missing, i tried a lot of things but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener) says:

> When using @KafkaHandler methods, the payload must have already been converted to the domain object (so the match can be performed). Use a custom deserializer, the `JsonDeserializer`, or the `JsonMessageConverter` with its TypePrecedence set to `TYPE_ID`. See Serialization, Deserialization, and Message Conversion for more information.

In order to route to the proper method, the `ConsumerRecord` must already have the correct type in it.

> `config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class );`

You are not providing the deserializer with any information about what object to create.

When Spring is the producer, it adds type information in record headers which can be used by the deserializer to construct the right type.

If there is no type information, you'll get a `Map`.

The producer has to set the type headers for this to work.

When the `@KaflaListener` is at the method level, we can determine the type to create from the method paramters. At the class level, we have a catch-22 - we can't choose a method unless the record already has been converted.

Your producer doesn't have to know the actual type, but it at least has to provide a header that can be used to look up the type we need to convert to.

See [Mapping Types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types).

Alternatively, the producer's JSON serializer must be configured to add type information into the JSON itself.

Another option is a custom deserializer that "peeks" at the JSON to determine what class to instantiate.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your reply. Sorry , I am a little confused, how would i tell my Deserializer what object to create, If any time, A Foo or a Bar object  comes in, how do i mention whether to convert the message to Bar or a Foo Object.Do you have an example where a custom deserializer or a JsonMessageCOnverter with its specific TypePrecedence is set. I am very new to Spring kafka. I guess if we do that it should be enough to make it work ? Also, if producer is other than spring, do i need to get the type headers set befre producer publsh msg. Any example for your answer would be of great help .

Comment: `>how would i tell my Deserializer what object to create` - that's exactly the problem the framework has - how can it tell which method to call when all it has is some JSON? The simplest solution is to configure the producer to add type information to the JSON; otherwise it must set a header to tell the deserializer which type to create. Or, let's say you have two types `Order` and `Invoice`. Perhaps there is some field in the JSON that only an Order has. Then, your custom desrializer can look at the JSON and if it has a field `onlyInAnOrder` create an `Order`, otherwise, create an `Invoice`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the Custom Deserializer where it should identify based on some field in the Order or Invoice object as per your example. To resolve my scenario further, in case I have Order and Invoice objects coming to the same topic and to avoid the Deserializer, would it be an alternate solution to change the publisher to post String Json equivalent for both Objects, and consume/deserialize them as String instead of a json object, and later convert to the required Object based on a certain field in the json string. I want to make sure it is a good practice and can be implemented.

Comment: It's better to do it in the deserializer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Is it good to use the Deserializer even if i dont have any control on the message producer? I may not get the headers i expect from publisher. Is the any doc that i can refer to create an insert the custom deserializer into the containerFactory

Comment: Just implement the `Deserializer` interface (`deserialize()` method). And then `config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,MySmartJsonDeserializer.class);`

Comment: Thanks @Gary. I will let you know how it goes after i finish implementing this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks Gary. Worked just as expected

Comment: Your question stimulated me [to add a new feature in the next release](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#serdes-type-methods) where the deserializer can call into your code to determine what type to convert to.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that would be awesome,  around what timeframe do u plan to release that piece of code.

Comment: The 2.5.0.RC1 (release candidate) is scheduled for tomorrow; the 2.5.0 release is currently planned for May 13.

Comment: Thanks Gary.. looking forward

Comment: Gary, Do we need to Have Custom Json Deserializer in case we use one listenerContainerFactory for Multiple @KafkaListeners, each Independent Listener having its own Object type. currently i use JsonDeserializer for the listenerContainerFactory  that i am trying to share for all the KafkaListeners. Thanks

Comment: You can override properties on each `@KafkaListener`. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#listener-group-id). That's the title of the next section; just scroll up a little the see the last example in the previous section.

Comment: This would let me add the properties, in this case a Deserializer on an individual KafkaListener annotation, I made my factory generic, and do i have to mention a seperate Deserializer on each Listener

Comment: All my @KafkaListeners would get a Different JSON Object from different topics, with my generic factory, when i send a message to one of the topics, i get this:   The class 'com.abc.MyObject' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*). I aleady have config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*"); in the configs

Comment: It will work just fine, because of type erasure at runtime. Set consumer property `spring.json.trusted.packages=*` (or `com.abc`).

Comment: Should i add properties on  @KafkaListener ? I am not adding it as of now, I am just using JsonDeserializer in factory, and trying to consume the message from one of the Topic, is that what i should do ?  I also have added trust packages as above, i am still getting  the trust packages error.

Comment: Factory should be fine; I suggest you ask a new question showing your current configuration.

Comment: Sure Will do that in a new question.